# How to e2e test websites with disabled JavaScript and noscript tags?

Tags: testing, cypress, nightwatch.js, testcafe, nightmare

I want to e2e test a website like when a user visits it with disabled javascript and/or some scripts blocked.

cypress.io does not (officially) support testing websites with disabled JS so therefore one can not e2e test what users would see in case they are securely visiting the website without JS enabled.

Nightmare JS seems to support it via browser options to disable JS for each `Nightmare` instance but I haven't tried its performance yet.

Any suggestions for a 2e2 testing tool that allows my scenario to be tested?

Answer (score 3):

Some testing frameworks do not support this scenario when JavaScript is disabled because they inject their scripts in the tested pages and run them during the test execution. For instance, TestCafe requires JavaScript to inject its scripts.

Comment: But not all the tools work on this principle of injecting. do they? Some tools communicate using REST APIs. don't they?

Comment: @Raju, I am using TestCafe, so I can say for sure only for TestCafe.

Comment: Injecting code essentially could also modify the page in testing. That's generally a no go. I have cypress.io almost at the point to allow my scenario, it requires to disable XSS protection for some weird reason.
Read on from here:
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1611#issuecomment-623793142